# Rewrite javascript functions for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some functions that either kill the page or fail silently in IE. I can't figure out how to rewrite them. I'd prefer not to have to add a bunch of plugins but I do have jQuery. 
The variables in question are arrays of objects. How would you write the following?

```
// 1. Get only the newly added user / group
var new_students = new_enrollee_list.filter(function( new_enrollee ){
    return ! current_enrollee_list.some(function( current_enrollee ){
        return new_enrollee.id === current_enrollee.id && new_enrollee.type === current_enrollee.type;
    });
});



// 2. Remove students from current list
current_enrollee_list.splice(0, current_enrollee_list.length, ...new_enrollee_list);
```

Comment: Your functions appear fine. How to rewrite them depends entirely on how you want them rewritten... which you have omitted.

Comment: This smells like homework to me...

Comment: When you say `fail silently` -- Have you tried breaking up your code and outputting values to the console in an attempt to debug **where** the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that `filter` and `some` don't work on IE and `...new_enrollee_list` breaks in IE. I tried rewriting them using `indexOf` but apparently, that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe do some research into what exactly `filter` and `some` are, and what `...new_enrollee_list` is. We're not here to do your homework for you. I'll give you a hint for the last one - look up "destructuring"

Comment: What version of IE?  Because `some` and `filter` supposedly work in IE9 and up, although spread syntax is a definite no.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham Not homework. I already did exactly that for 2-3 hours. Still couldn't get the right syntax.

Comment: @James IE9 and up

Comment: Why do you want to get all the new students then remove the ONLY new students from the current enrolled list.  By definition, the current list will not have the new students?

Comment: @nfn neil because the user picker that is already implemented allows for adding and removing of both groups and individuals. I need to submit that to the database and then update a separate table without duplicates whilst keeping track of how they were added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the spread syntax you should be able to workaround by making one array from all the arguments and using [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

So this

```
current_enrollee_list.splice(0, current_enrollee_list.length, ...new_enrollee_list);
```

becomes

```
current_enrollee_list.splice.apply(current_enrollee_list, [0, current_enrollee_list.length].concat(new_enrollee_list));
```

Since you are using IE9 `some` and `filter` should work fine.

Comment: null didn't work but this did:
`current_enrollee_list.splice.apply(current_enrollee_list, [0, current_enrollee_list.length].concat(new_enrollee_list));`

And you were right about the `some` and `filter`.